# c# which collection to use multiple producers and a single consumer?

Tags: c#, multithreading, producer-consumer

I have a bunch of threads producing objects (e.g. strings) and a single thread consuming batch of objects (e.g. serializing them and sending yo a remote server).

I want producers to be able to pish data as fast as possible. They should never lock because of other producers, not even by the consumer. Is this possible? How?

Comment: This seems te be a job for `ConcurrentQueue`, but the requirement "*they should never lock*" is a bit unclear. If you are working multithreaded and are willing to create a collection which is accessibly by multiple threads, your arw definitely going to need locks.

Comment: Perhaps `BlockingCollection` ? and what do you mean by *They should never lock* ? and what about *Thread safety* concerns ?

Comment: ConcurrentBag has this concept of per thread list. AFAIK, multiple Add calls will never block. A consumer could use a interlock swap to consume each thread list. I wonder whether c# has something built in already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which by default wraps a `ConcurrentQueue`.

> BlockingCollection is a thread-safe collection class that provides
>   the following features:
>
> An implementation of the Producer-Consumer pattern.
>
> Concurrent adding and taking of items from multiple threads.

Comment: Does BlockingCollection ever block on Adds? Assuming it is unbounded, of course.